# Format a hard drive to work with Windows

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, formatting

I have a external hard drive formatted to Mac OS (journaled).

I no longer have a Mac, so I would like to format the hard drive to exFat or fat32 from my Windows computer.

My computer detects the drive but it does not show up in File Explorer.

It does not give me the option to format it in Devices and Printers in the Control Panel.

Comment: Try diskpart tool in command promt.

Comment: FAT32 and exFAT are honestly horrible choices and are in legacy support.  You really should be using NTFS instead.

Comment: @Ramhound exFAT sounds like a reasonable choice to me. It's quite modern (newer than NTFS), doesn't support permissions (which you probably don't want on external drive) and is designed to be portable.

Comment: FAT32 is arguably the best choice. It has the least patent issues, and many of the patented features of NTFS are not useful for an external drive anyway. exFAT is a classical Microsoft land grab and has no technical justification. It _definitely_ is not intended to be portable, as can be seen from the lack of an free&open standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use Window's Disk Management console to modify your partitions.  Once you have removed the existing partition(s) from the drive, create new ones that Windows recognizes and then format them.

How to do this is available in Microsoft's online help:

- [Create and format a hard disk partition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7)
- [Can I repartition my hard disk?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/repartition-hard-disk#1TC=windows-7)

> 1. Open Computer Management by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Security**, clicking **Administrative Tools**, and then double-clicking **Computer Management**.‌  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>      password or provide confirmation.
> 2. In the left pane, under **Storage**, click **Disk Management**.

Alternatively, just run `diskmgmt.msc`.

Comment: Computer Management (or how it was called there) is readily available via Start->right click on Computer->the option there (I don't have a Windows machine right now to check how it was called there). No need to go through Control Panel. +1 anyway.